# How to find out which view is focused?

Tags: android

I need to find out if any view is focused inside an Activity and what view it is. How to do this?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Call [`getCurrentFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29) on the Activity.

Comment: For some reason it returns null after cycling all child views with "next" action.

Comment: BTW, getCurrentFocus() is a method of activity, not of view.

Comment: ... so in fragments we can use getActivity().getCurrentFocus().clearFocus() e.g...

Comment: It is possible to [get hosting Activity from a View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276634/android-get-hosting-activity-from-a-view) and call `getCurrentFocus()`, but not that reliable.

Comment: kotlin: in fragment - `activity?.currentFocus`

Comment: From view: `(v.context as? Activity)?.currentFocus`.

Answer (score 13):

From the source of Activity:

```
   /**
     * Calls {@link android.view.Window#getCurrentFocus} on the
     * Window of this Activity to return the currently focused view.
     * 
     * @return View The current View with focus or null.
     * 
     * @see #getWindow
     * @see android.view.Window#getCurrentFocus
     */
    public View getCurrentFocus() {
        return mWindow != null ? mWindow.getCurrentFocus() : null;
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this instead, put everything inside a `thread` and print the *id* and *classname* live to `logcat`. Just put this code inside your `Activity`, in the `onCreate` method then look into your `logcat` to see what is currently focused.

## JAVA

```
  new Thread(() -> {
        int oldId = -1;
        while (true) {
            View newView= this.getCurrentFocus();
            if (newView != null && newView.getId() != oldId) {
                oldId = view.getId();
                String idName = "";
                try {
                   idName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(newView.getId());
                 } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                   idName = String.valueOf(newView.getId());
                 }
                Log.i(TAG, "Focused Id: \t" + idName + "\tClass: \t" + newView.getClass());
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

## KOTLIN

```
      Thread(Runnable {
            var oldId = -1
            while (true) {
                val newView: View? = this.currentFocus
                if (newView != null && newView.id != oldId) {
                    oldId = newView.id
                    var idName: String = try {
                        resources.getResourceEntryName(newView.id)
                    } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
                        newView.id.toString()
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Focused Id: \t" + idName + "\tClass: \t" + newView.javaClass)
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100)
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }).start()
```

*Be aware this thread runs in a 100ms cycle so it doesn't overflow the CPU with unnecessary work.*

Comment: You could extend this code and add a highlight so you can see which item is selected. It should work as long the item is inside the screen. But using the `logcat` is much more secure.

Answer (score 10):

if you are in a fragment you can use

```
getView().findFocus()
```

Answer (score 6):

for some reason getCurrentFocus() method isn't available anymore; probably it's deprecated already, here the working alternative:

```
View focusedView = (View) yourParentView.getFocusedChild();
```

Comment: It is two different methods. getCurrentFocus() is an Activity class method and getFocusedChild() belongs to View class

Comment: @BoredT: `getFocusedChild()` is a method on `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

ViewGroup has quite convenient method for retrieving focused child:

```
ViewGroup.getFocusedChild()
```