# Android support library 23.4.0: android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper cannot be cast to Activity

Tags: android, android-support-library

So I updated to the latest support libraries, and got a crash I am not able to fix. My build.gradle now has these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    // More stuff...
}
```

I had a working listener that is used to catch clicks and start a new Activity. This was working fine in support libraries v. 23.1.0, but not in 23.4.0 (and 23.3.0):

```
public class IngredientItemOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
    private Ingredient mIngredient;

    public IngredientItemOnClickListener(Ingredient ingredient)
    {
        mIngredient= ingredient;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) view.getContext(); // <-- crash here
        myActivity.showIngredientActivity(mIngredient);
    }
}
```

This listener is simply attached to an `ImageButton` and thereafter the color of the Button is tinted, like this:

```
Ingredient ingredient = getIngredient();
myImageButton.setOnClickListener(new IngredientItemOnClickListener(ingredient));
Drawable drawable = Tinting.tint(myActivity, R.drawable.my_icon, R.color.red);
myImageButton.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

where `Tinting.tint()` is my own tinting function:

```
public class Tinting
{
    @Nullable
    public static Drawable tint(Context context, int drawableId, int colorId)
    {
        final Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
        if (drawable != null)
        {
            final Drawable wrapped = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
            drawable.mutate();
            DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapped, ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorId));
        }
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

Previously when I clicked the button everything worked as expected, but now the Context of the View seems to have changed to `TintContextWrapper` which I can find little information about. I found [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208643), but the project member advises to ask here on StackOverflow, so here it is.

#### What have I tried?

Since the project member in the Google issue stated *You will need to obtain the activity from the wrapped context.* I tried casting to `TintContextWrapper` instead of `MyActivity`, which works fine, but I cannot figure out how to get `MyActivity` from `TintContextWrapper`.

#### So my questions are:

1. How can I get `MyActivity` from the `TintContextWrapper`?
2. Why is my `ImageButton` suddenly wrapped in a `TintContextWrapper`.
3. Should this behavior really be expected?

#### Definition of ImageButton in xml is simply:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/my_id"
    android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />
```

#### Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper cannot be cast to com.my.app.activities.MyActivity
    at com.my.app.listeners.IngredientItemOnClickListener.onClick(IngredientItemOnClickListener.java:21)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Logs depict `MyItemOnClickListener` . Where is it ?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error on my side, I update the stack trace. The crash is in `IngredientItemOnClickListener` which is attached in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. both activity n TintContextWRapper comes from `ContextWrapper`. `ContextWrapper` have a method `getBaseContext()`. It should be easy to create a loop method that checks `instanceof WrapContext`, gets base context and then checks `instanceof Activity`. (If you have problems with this method comment here that I'll dig on some project of mine and paste here to u)
2. Because AppCompat wraps your context to be able to inject "compat" views and "compat" tinting and other "compat" stuff. That's normal.
3. Yes. That's how AppCompat does its thing.

Comment: Thanks, I never realized that was how the `ContextWrapper` classes worked and why.

Comment: The code for the "loop method that checks instanceof WrapContext" can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32973351

Answer (score 4):

@Krøllebølle

> Android support library 23.4.0:
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper cannot be cast to
>   Activity

Answer to you question is :
first your click event code should be like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    MyActivity myActivity = getRequiredActivity(view);
    myActivity.showIngredientActivity(mIngredient);
}
```

and then write function getRequiredActivity():

```
private Activity getRequiredActivity(View req_view) {
    Context context = req_view.getContext();
    while (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            return (Activity)context;
        }
        context = ((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and your Crash/Exception is fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to pass a reference of your activity into the onClickListener to avoid the issue with `TintContextWrapper`. Giving your class a reference to `MyActivity` is simple and avoids possible casting issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
Activity activity = (Activity) view.getRootView().getContext()
```

Gets the context that contains this view without the wrapper of android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper.

Comment: simple solution that fixed my problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can I get MyActivity from the TintContextWrapper?

You really shouldn't. There's no guaranteed that a View's Context will be an Activity -- definitely not a specific Activity. Where are you setting your OnClickListener? I'm assuming that at the place where you set the listener, you will have access to the Activity. For example, if you're setting the listener from an Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.ingredientButton).setOnClickListener(
                new IngredientItemOnClickListener(yourIngredient));
    }

    void showIngredientActivity(Ingredient ingredient) {
        // Do your stuff
    }

    public class IngredientItemOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        private Ingredient mIngredient;

        public IngredientItemOnClickListener(Ingredient ingredient) {
            mIngredient = ingredient;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showIngredientActivity(mIngredient);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the listener is always set within a given Activity that extends AppCompatActivity, more specific inside an Adapter of a RecyclerView in that Activity. Multiple items in the RecyclerView will have this ImageButton, but the Ingredient item will vary with each instance of the button. In such case, could the Context ever be something else? Direct casting to MyActivity seems to work fine as @Budiud suggested.

Comment: I would say that's it's "not the right thing". It may work, but there's nothing in the API that guarantees it won't break again in another library release. For your case, I would recommend adding an interface to your RecyclerView (something like OnIngredientClickedListener) and provider a setter that your Activity would provide an instance of. Then, have a private OnClickListener in the RecyclerView that will forward the clicks up to the OnIngredientClickedListener. That removes your hard dependency on MainActivity.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll try to do something like that and in a few other places in my code as well. It is worth noting, however, that the project member in [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208643) suggest getting the Activity from the wrapped context. That person could be "mistaken" of course.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after updating Android Support Libraries.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and is resolved with 
- Android Support Library, revision 24.2.1 (September 2016)
- compileSdkVersion 24
- buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"