# Coroutine on an extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging, kotlin-extension

I am using extension function to bind list data to recyclerview , with pagedlist it doesn't need any coroutine

```
@BindingAdapter("pagedListAdapterData")
fun <T : Any> submitPagedList(recyclerView: RecyclerView, list: PagedList<T>?) {
    if (list != null && recyclerView.adapter is PagedListAdapter<*, *>) {
        (recyclerView.adapter as? PagedListAdapter<T, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>)?.submitList((list))
    }
}

        pagedListAdapterData="@{viewModel.list}"
```

but as im upgrading to Paging 3.0 it requires the use of coroutine

```
@BindingAdapter("pagingDataAdapter")
fun <T : Any> submitPagingDataList(recyclerView: RecyclerView, list: PagingData<T>?) {
    if (list != null && recyclerView.adapter is PagingDataAdapter<*, *>) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            (recyclerView.adapter as? PagingDataAdapter<T, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>)?.submitData((list))
        }
    }
}
```

this works just fine, but my worry is on the use of Globalscope, seems like there is a better way to do it since globalScope is not recomended

Comment: The recommended way is to start a Coroutine and keep track of it, as you have to destroy it when your view is destroyed. I don't know, if a BindingAdapter is a good purpose for this, because without it, it would be easier

Comment: exactly , i can  submitData in the fragment on a viewmodel scoped coroutine....but i wanted to know if there's maybe a way to use coroutine in a databindingAdapter

Comment: Well you **could** use Coroutines, but you **shouldn't** do it. Reason for this: It might be very hard or even impossible to keep a good track of your started Coroutine outside your BindingAdapter. You might have to do some magic, to properly achieve is, but magic is **bad**. I know, BindingAdapters can be very handy, but sometimes they are overkill. If you'd like, I can share my way to easily submit the paging Data to the adapter.

Comment: Please do , this is how i did it outside the BindingAdapter     
 viewModel.list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                adapter.submitData(it)
            }
        })

Answer (score 5):

`androidx.lifecycle` has an extension function `View.findViewTreeLifecycleOwner`, so you don't have to create your own:

```
view.findViewTreeLifecycleOwner()?.lifecycleScope?.launch {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you , you saved me after wasting a long time

Comment: Didn't know about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it isn't a good idea to use the `GlobalScope`, [according to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data#display-paged-data) `submitData()` should be run inside 'lifecycleScope'. You can get 'lifecycleScope' from the view, but it requires a little bit of boilerplate:

```kotlin
package com.test.pagingadapter

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.view.View
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.findFragment
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.paging.PagingData
import androidx.paging.PagingDataAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/58249983/4858777
 */
tailrec fun Context?.getActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this

    else -> {
        val contextWrapper = this as? ContextWrapper
        contextWrapper?.baseContext?.getActivity()
    }
}

val View.lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner? get() = try {
    val fragment = findFragment<Fragment>()
    fragment.viewLifecycleOwner
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
    when (val activity = context.getActivity()) {
        is ComponentActivity -> activity
        else -> null
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("pagingDataAdapter")
fun <T : Any> submitPagingDataList(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: PagingData<T>?) {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter
    if (data != null && adapter is PagingDataAdapter<*, *>) {
        // but it isn't a perfect solution because the cast is required
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val castedAdapter = adapter as PagingDataAdapter<T, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>

        recyclerView.lifecycleOwner?.lifecycleScope?.launch {
            castedAdapter.submitData(data)
        }
    }
}
```