# how to get current focus element in Horizontalscroll view?

Tags: android, focus, scrollview

I implement scroll view to display element of view...[image: Scroll view in center with two button on left and right button to shift scroll]

now in this scenario I want to shift focus from scroll view to button.

does any one have idea about it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352209/how-to-find-out-which-view-is-focused

Comment: thanks anukool..but in case of scroll view how we can get focus for inner item.

Answer (score 1):

Option I:  Using `getLocationOnScreen` on all Child Views inside `ScrollView`

1. Get instance of scroll view.

   `ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollViewID);`
2. Type cast into ViewGroup

   `ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)scrollView;`
3. Find all child views of `ViewGroup`  ( check Android Documentation )

   Get rectangle representing location of Child View on screen by calling  - getLocationOnScreen

   getLocationOnScreen will store x,y coordinates in Rect object, compare rect x,y coordinates to see if Rectangles lies within screen bounds. ( You can get screen by using getLocationOnScreen on Content View /  Root View )

Option II:  `getGlobalVisibleRect` on All child views inside `ScrollView`  ( Quick and Easy )

1. Get all child views inside ScrollView.  Call `getGlobalVisibleRect` on each of the child views, if it returns true, it means at-least some of portion of the child view is visible.

Comment: Pardeep, this #makesense. I'll give it try.