# How to go to next Edit text in android after enter value in first one?

Tags: android, android-edittext

We enter value in first `EditText`. Now I want when we press done button then cursor move to next `EditText`.

I tried to do it and search on Google but nothing found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android XML - moving between EditText fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223852/android-xml-moving-between-edittext-fields)

Answer (score 3):

You can get `DONE` button click and set focus to next `EditText`

```
first_edit_text.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                 if(actionId == 0 || actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
                 {
                     next_edit_text.requestFocus();
                 }
                return false;
            }
      });
```

**EDIT :**

To fulfill your requirement :

```
public void setEditText() {
        edittext = new EditText[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            edittext[i] = new EditText(this);
            edittext[i].setId(i);
            edittext[i].setSingleLine();
            edittext[i].setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            edittext[i].setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == 0 || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                        int current_id= v.getId();
                        if((current_id+1)!=length){
                                 edittext[current_id+1].requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            linear.addView(edittext[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edit text which used in this app is created programatically so what we do

Comment: public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  
  EditText edit_text = (EditText) arg0;
  sb.append(edit_text.getText().toString().trim());
  edit_text.setSingleLine();
  edit_text.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

Comment: First edittext is created or not?? You just have to add EditorActionListener on it..

Comment: we create edittext using for loop public void setEditText() {
edittext = new EditText[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
edittext[i] = new EditText(this);
edittext[i].setId(i);
edittext[i].setSingleLine();
edittext[i].setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
edittext[i].setOnEditorActionListener(this);
linear.addView(edittext[i]);}}

Comment: OK so what's the issue now?? And put your code in pastie.org so atleast readable to all

Comment: we also get the value but when we fill the first edit text then it value get when we click on done button on soft keyboard. this process repeat for all edit text. And i want when we fill first edit text and click done the the keyboard automatically open we just fill value and click done.

Comment: Sorry but Can't get what you wanna say :(

Comment: @ SweetWhiser Your code working for me but a little issue is that when we fill value in last edit text and press done the app will be crashed  . I think according to your this logic :-                       int current_id= v.getId(); 
if(current_id!=length)            ((EditText)findViewById(current_id+1)).requestFocus();             when we reach last edittext the can not find next edit text.

Comment: Ya you need to handle that case dear...write else block accordingly

Comment: Check edited answer.I have changed the if condition...Now it will work..And dont forget to accept the answer if it worked for you..Best luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Please use imeOptions in EditText.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: I guess he doesn't want to go to next on the click on next button of soft keyboard..So your answer is not relevent..

Answer (score 2):

You can try triggering Next key's click in `onClick` of DONE key as shown here:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NEXT); //trigger Next key's click here 
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

After entering the value in the text,
to go to next edit box you can type in the xml layout editbox code as following:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/here your next edit box id"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place `android:singleLine="true"` on your `EditText` it will automatically change the **Enter** button on your keyboard into a **Next** button.