# Android move cursor from one edit text to another on button click

Tags: android, cursor, android-edittext, cursor-position

I want to shift my cursor from one edit text to another which are placed vertically.

But i want it to shift on a button click i.e., when i click on the button it should directly move onto the next edit text and even it should perform the desired task.

I am making use of "holder" to hold the data present in the list.
any suggestions...????

code is:

```
holder.txtSrc = (EditText) convertView .findViewById(R.id.txt_src_word);
holder.btnTranslate .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        // translate text 
        txtSrc.requestFocus(); 
        Button bt = (Button) v; 
        pos = (Integer) bt.getTag();
        translate(); } });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your efforts before asking for solutions, thanks.

Comment: My issue is for example:

EditText txtSrc;
--------
holder.txtSrc = (EditText) convertView      .findViewById(R.id.txt_src_word);
---
holder.btnTranslate
      .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // translate text
        
      txtSrc.requestFocus();
        Button bt = (Button) v;

        pos = (Integer) bt.getTag();

        translate();

       }
      });
it shows error in "txtSrc".requestFocus();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android XML - moving between EditText fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223852/android-xml-moving-between-edittext-fields)

Answer (score 1):

In edittext thier is an  `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` use that

Comment: My issue is for example:

EditText txtSrc;
--------
holder.txtSrc = (EditText) convertView      .findViewById(R.id.txt_src_word);
---
holder.btnTranslate
      .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // translate text
        
      txtSrc.requestFocus();
        Button bt = (Button) v;

        pos = (Integer) bt.getTag();

        translate();

       }
      });
it shows error in "txtSrc".requestFocus();

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `editText.requestFocus();` on button click

OR

There is another way to do it simply by using the following attribute

> android:imeOptions="actionNext"

For example :

```
<EditText
android:hint="@string/hint_user_name"
android:id="@+id/et_user_name"
android:maxLines="2"
style="@style/EditText_Login"
android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
/>
```

Thanks,

Comment: i have gone through every post related to this topic but none of them made me resolve my issue...
My issue is for example:

EditText txtSrc;
--------
holder.txtSrc = (EditText) convertView      .findViewById(R.id.txt_src_word);
---
holder.btnTranslate
      .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // translate text
        
      txtSrc.requestFocus();
        Button bt = (Button) v;

        pos = (Integer) bt.getTag();

        translate();

       }
      });

Comment: here you need to use holder.txtSrc.requestFocus();

Comment: now it gives error in "holder".txtSrc.requestFocus();