# Is possible in android to know which view gains focus from the current view that looses it?

Tags: android, focus

I have an activity with 2 types of views `EditText` and `CustomEditText` my custom edit text has a `onFocusChanged()`method and I can know when the view gains and looses focus, but I would like to know which view gains focus in order to perform different actions, is possible to know **from the `onFocusChanged()` method** which view got focus after this view looses it?

Calling `getCurrentFocus()` from the overwritten method in a custom view like this will return null so that will not work

```
@Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if (focused ) {

        }else{
            Activity activity = (Activity) this.getContext();
            activity.getCurrentFocus();//this returns null
        }

        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }
```

Comment: Call `getCurrentFocus()` on the Activity. as per [How to find out which view is focused?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352209/how-to-find-out-which-view-is-focused)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out which view is focused?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352209/how-to-find-out-which-view-is-focused)